# Create a Localhost(Virtualhost-configured) SSL Certificate in Ubuntu 20.04 with XAMPP

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

Just wanted to know the way to generate ssl for my localhost using Ubuntu 20.04 with installed Xampp. I wanted to use the Apache that comes with the Xampp (which means I don't have the external Apache installed via apt. I also have used virtual host instead of the native localhost:port url.

I am having a bit of a hard time since the word Ubuntu + Xampp doesn't generally coexist on the forums that I have searched. They are basically Ubuntu + external Apache or Windows + Xampp.

I tried some things using those forum tips but I ended up with chrome having this error [image: error]

even though I already enabled `Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost.` I also tried clearing Chrome's cache but nothing really made any difference.

Would really appreciate everything for your help. Thank you.

Comment: The error message is about "example.test" which means that you don't use "localhost" in the URL. Neither creating a certificate for localhost nor allowing invalid certificates for localhost will work, if you don't actually use localhost.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ah yes. That's another thing I forgot to include, I configured my Xampp to use virtual host instead of using localhost with port. I was able to generate crt and key solely for that url but that's the result of deploying it. Am i missing something?

Comment: The setting about invalid certificate is only valid for localhost - which you don't use. So you would explicitly need to add your generated certificate as trusted to the browser.